# Navigation Bar Item Image is not visible

Tags: ios, swift2, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I trying to implement a hamburger menu using a scroll view, two container views and two embedded views with Swift 2  and Xcode 7. Everything works but for some reason, I can't see the picture of the Navigation Item I set. However if I click on the area where the Item is supposed to be it responds as I expect. But I can't figure out why I can see the Nav bar item image?

Any idea what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the image that you're trying to set is added to your project. Not the project folder but the actual Xcode project and used in the target that you're currently using.
My guess is that you're setting the image with

```
UIImage(named:"YourImageName")
```

Also, another hint is that you can make your button visible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. But the image is in the actual Xcode project.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my bug. I had copy a piece of code to create the menu image and paste it in a class with the same name. So the image was never created. But Xcode didn't complained that I have a nested class of the same name as the main class, that would have helped so much :-/